# vim tidy makeprg with stdin

Tags: html, vim, vi, tidy

I've got this in .vim/ftplugin/html.vim:

```
set makeprg=%!tidy\ -q\ -i\ --show-warnings\ no
```

If I do make in a html file I get this error:

```
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"
```

When I execute this:

```
:%!tidy -q -i --show-warnings no
```

It works beautifully. What am I doing wrong with my set makeprg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `makeprg` was intended to be used that way. I suggest you simply define your own mapping or command

```
:map ,m :%!tidy -q -i --show-warnings no<CR>
:Command Make %!tidy -q -i --show-warnings no<CR>
```

`%!` replaces the contents of the buffer with the output of the following command, but  when calling `:make`, the `%` is replaced with the file name for the current buffer. The error comes, because your current buffer is not editing a file, so the `%` replacement can't take place.

Comment: I added this to my .vimrc:
`command Tidy %!tidy -q -i --show-warnings no<CR>`